# How to check one place is present in route or not using Google Directions API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have one place I want to check that place is present between route of Source and Destination using Google Directions API.

for example:
A - source
B - destination
and 
C - is the place.

Now i want to check that C is present or not in A to B route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directionsRoute contains a `overview_path`-property, whih defines a simplified path for the route.

You may use this path to create a polyline and then use [google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly) to check if the place is on the route.

As the `overview_path` is simplified, you can use the path-property of the [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DirectionsStep) to create a more detailed route(polyline) and get a more accurate result.